# Inversion formula for characteristic functions whose argument is complex with non-zero real part

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10203-011-0124-0) they use an inversion formula for characteristic functions whose argument is complex with non-zero real part. Namely, given a random variable $X$ taking values in $(0,\infty)$, they consider the characteristic function in the following way
\begin{align*}
f(\phi)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi X}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi_R X+ i\phi_I X}\right],
\end{align*}
where $\phi=\phi_R+i\phi_I\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi_R,\phi_I\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $f$ may not be well-defined, as opposed to the *standard* characteristic function that is always well-defined. Then, in Equation (A8) of [the paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10203-011-0124-0) they obtain the density function $p$ of the random variable $X$ using the following inversion theorem
\begin{align*}
p(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty\Re\left[e^{-\phi x}f(\phi)\right]d\phi_I.
\end{align*}
I would like to know if there is some reference for this result or if it can be deduced from the existing inversion theorems for *standard* characteristic functions. For instance, the previous inversion formula looks like a generalization of the Gil-Pelaez inversion formula, that is, if we consider the characteristic function $\varphi(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right]$ where now $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then,
\begin{align*}
p(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty\Re\left[e^{-it x}\varphi(t)\right]dt.
\end{align*}

So far, I have been able to prove that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty\Re\left[e^{-\phi x}f(\phi)\right]d\phi_I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\phi_Rx-i\phi_Ix}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi_RX+i\phi_IX}\right]d\phi_I
\end{align*}
Note that if $\phi_R=0$ in the previous expression we recover the usual inversion formula given by
\begin{align*}
p(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\phi_Ix}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{i\phi_IX}\right]d\phi_I
\end{align*}

Any help on how to prove this inversion theorem or any reference of the inversion theorem used in the paper would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to prove it using existing inversion theorems. I think this should work:

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable and $\phi_R\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi_R X}\right]<\infty$. Write $f(\phi)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi  X}\right]$ where $\phi=\phi_R+i\phi_I\in\mathbb{C}, \phi_R,\phi_I\in\mathbb{R}$ is the *generalized* Fourier transform. We assume that $t\to f(\phi_R+it)$ is integrable in $[0,\infty)$ and that $X$ has a density function $p$.

Define the random variable $Y$ that has density function given by
\begin{align*}
p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{K}e^{\phi_R y}p(y)
\end{align*}
where $K=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\phi_R x}p(x)dx=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\phi_R X}\right]<\infty$. Note that the characteristic function of $Y$ is given by
\begin{align*}
     f_Y(i\phi_I)&=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{i\phi_I Y}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\phi_I y}p_Y(y)dy=\frac{1}{K}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\phi_I y}e^{\phi_R y}p(y)dy
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
     &=\frac{1}{K}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\left(\phi_R+i\phi_I\right) X}\right]=\frac{1}{K}f(\phi_R+i\phi_I).
\end{align*}
Since $t\to f(\phi_R+it)=f_Y(it)$ is integrable in $[0,\infty)$, by the Gil-Pelaez inversion theorem the following holds
\begin{align*}
    p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \Re\left[e^{-i\phi_I y}f_Y(i\phi_I)\right]d\phi_I .
\end{align*}
Introducing the equivalent expressions for $p_Y$ and $f_Y$ we get
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{K}e^{\phi_R y}p(y)&=\frac{1}{K\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \Re\left[e^{-i\phi_I y}f(\phi_R+i\phi_I)\right]d\phi_I \\
  \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    p(y)&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \Re\left[e^{-\left(\phi_R+i\phi_I\right)y}f(\phi_R+i\phi_I)\right]d\phi_I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \Re\left[e^{-\phi y}f(\phi)\right]d\phi_I.
  \end{align*}
This finishes the proof.